# Как сравнить все отправляемые заголовки

Tags: php, curl

С помощью библиотеки Curl посылаю данные, в ответ получаю ошибку 500. 
Т.е. передал неправильный параметр либо заголовки.

Как можно проверить, какие заголовки и куки передаются? И чего не хватает?

```
{
$ch = curl_init();
$ref="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36";    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // отправляем на 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // пустые заголовки
$request = 'Host: gstime.e-autopay.com
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Origin:https://gstime.e-autopay.com
Referer:https://gstime.e-autopay.com/adminka/login
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection:keep-alive';
$split = explode("\n",$request);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$split ); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 40);// таймаут4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); #PHP>5.3.6 dirname(__FILE__) -> __DIR__
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); #PHP>5.3.6 dirname(__FILE__) -> __DIR__
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 ); // использовать данные в post
if($post)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 $curl=curl_exec($ch);

$data = new simple_html_dom();
$data->load($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($status);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

Посылаю след. данные. Куки в файл сохраняются правильно.

```
$auth = array(
'login'=>'login',
'password'=>'password',
 '_token'=>$token
 );
 echo request2($url,$auth);
```

Кто может помочь с этим вопросом? Как еще можно понять, что не так?

Comment: Переменной $url не хватает?)

Answer (score 1):

Поставь Fiddler. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Это локальный прокси-сервер. Соответственно, он перехватывает и отображает все проходяцие через него запросы. Смотреть их можно на вкладке Inspectors.

Сравниваешь в чём разница и подбираешь правильный комплект заголдовков.

Правый щелчок по запросу Replay -> Reissue from composer - текущий запрос попадёт на вкладку composer, где его можно будет модифицировать и снова отправлять. Таким образом либо чистишь правильный запрос до минимального набора заголовков, либо дополняешь неправильный.

Comment: Но я не могу узнать какие запросы уходят от меня в cUrl.

Comment: Curl не умеет работать через прокси?

Comment: а ккуки которые передаются как посмотреть?

Comment: @РадикКамалов, в соответствующем заголовке `cookie` в запросе и `set-cookie` в ответе. Вообще, советую на вкладке raw сравнивать - там весь запрос показан как есть. На остальных - только если есть подозрение, что посылаемые post'ом данные неверны. Кстати, там и отдельная вкладка cookies есть.

Comment: ничего не отображает. все пусто.

Comment: @РадикКамалов, значит они не отправляются. Что логично.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/answer.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Робот');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$sent_headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
curl_close($ch);
echo $sent_headers;
```